# How to return entire model from laravel in jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I want to return the list of posts that is requested by user by selecting form combobox such as PHP posts.
So i want to return `post_title`, `post_body` which i am able to return.
But i also want to return the `user_name`(owner of post) which is present in `users` table.

I have created one-to-one relationship between `Posts` and `Users` assuming a single user can post only one post

I am returning this

```
return \App\Post::where('post_topic', 'PHP')->get();
```

And my jquery ajax is

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

        $('#post_form').on('submit', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var post_topic = $('#post_select').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/test',
                data:{class: post_topic},
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function( data ) {

                    console.log(data);

                    var htmlText = '';

                    for ( var key in data ) {
                        htmlText += '<tr>';
                        htmlText += '<td class="">' + data[key].post_title + '</td>';
                        htmlText += '<td class="">' + data[key].post_body + '</td>';
                        htmlText += '<td class="">' + data[key].post_owner + '</td>';
                        htmlText += '</tr>';
                    }

                    $('#post_list').html(htmlText);
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

But this gives user_name as undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use with to get relationship data in laravel, before that please check if you have provided a proper relationship in eloquent

```
return \App\Post::where('post_topic', 'PHP')->get();
```

instead of this it should be in JSON format like

```
$posttopic = \App\Post::where('post_topic', 'PHP')->with('user')->get();

reutrn Response()->json($posttopic, 200);
```

200 is status code and please remember to include response facades

Comment: It gives this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' on this line return Response->json($posttopic, 200);

Comment: still in the console it only returns the post information but not the user information

Comment: have you provided proper relationship in models please check and use the updated answer using `with`

Comment: yes now it works. just one question is status 200 for success ?

Comment: @Raj Yes, 200 is for success. http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html or https://httpstatuses.com/